# Toast Message does not disappear

Tags: java, android, for-loop, toast, android-toast

I have a for loop and I'm doing some searching stuff in it. I want to show toast message when process is unsuccessful. I can show toast message but it does not disappear when I want to search again.

```
public String SearchInstallationBySerialNumber(String serial){
    String installation = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < _allItems.size(); i++){
        OsbDownloadItem currentOsbItem = _allItems.get(i);
        if(!currentOsbItem.getSerialNumber().equals(serial)){
            Toast.makeText(mActivity,
                           "unsuccessful searching",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            continue;
        }else{
            installation = currentOsbItem.getInstallation();
        }
    }
    return installation;
}
```

Comment: You might be calling this `Toast.makeText` again in the loop ? `continue `jumps to the next iteration right ?

Comment: Maybe you should save the toast and call toast.cancel() if you want to hide any old toast.

Comment: i cannot call Toast.cancel()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing Toast from for loop might help!

```
public String SearchInstallationBySerialNumber(String serial) {

    String installation = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < _allItems.size(); i++) {

        OsbDownloadItem currentOsbItem = _allItems.get(i);
        if (currentOsbItem.getSerialNumber().equals(serial)) {

            installation = currentOsbItem.getInstallation();
            break;
        }

    }
    if (installation == null) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "unsuccessful searching", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return installation;
}
```